# Book recommendation for Mathematical olympiads for a +2 student

Tags: secondary-education, reference-books, book

My Mathematics Olympiads are approaching So I have not started the preparation yet. I need to have a better resource for +2(11th or 12th class basically a high school student) Olympiads so if you have any suggestion pls go ahead :)

Comment: Have you checked for books on the Art of Problem Solving site? This one looks like it might be right: https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/book/aops-vol2

Comment: sure i will @SueVanHattum

Comment: Approaching? Just pointing out that you may competing against bright people your age who have (in addition to being bright) trained hard on Olympiad style questions for a year or two :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UK Mathematics Trust has published some books that may be suitable and are widely used in the UK: 'A Mathematical Olympiad Primer' and 'A Mathematical Olympiad Companion' by Geoff Smith. You can find them [here](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/shop). They are designed for help students prepare for the British Mathematics Olympiad rounds 1 and 2.

Comment: thanks alot @A.Goodier